# Setting maximum number of results in product category array

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

This code displays a list of images/links to products according to the category. Works great, but showing way too many results. Wondering if I can limit it to show just maximum of 8 at random?

Currently:

```
<?php

$prod_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', array(
    'orderby'    => 'name',
    'order'      => 'DSC',
    //'include'         => '39, 38, 37, 28, 26, 40',
    'exclude'           => '32, 38',
    'hide_empty' => 1
));

foreach( $prod_categories as $prod_cat ) :
    $cat_thumb_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $prod_cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
    //$cat_thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( 'Full Size', $cat_thumb_id );
    $cat_thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_url($cat_thumb_id, $size = 'full');
    $term_link = get_term_link( $prod_cat, 'product_cat' );

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the WordPress [get_terms() documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) you can use the `number` argument:

**Limiting the number of terms**

```
$prod_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', array(
    'orderby'    => 'name',
    'order'      => 'DSC',
    //'include'  => '39, 38, 37, 28, 26, 40',
    'exclude'    => '32, 38',
    'hide_empty' => 1,
    'number'     => 8
));
```

**Include / Exclude should be arrays**

Also, as a side-note, your include / exclude parameters are incorrect - they should be arrays:

```
$prod_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', array(
    'orderby'    => 'name',
    'order'      => 'DSC',
    //'include'  => array(39, 38, 37, 28, 26, 40),
    'exclude'    => array(32, 38),
    'hide_empty' => 1,
    'number'     => 8
));
```

**Random Terms?**

And lastly, you mention random.  `get_terms` does not support random order, so that would need to be done in PHP.  In order to do so, we'd want to **remove** the number limit, and then process the results in PHP, like so:

```
$prod_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', array(
    'orderby'    => 'name',
    'order'      => 'DSC',
    //'include'  => '39, 38, 37, 28, 26, 40',
    'exclude'    => '32, 38',
    'hide_empty' => 1
));

// Randomize
$prod_categories = shuffle($prod_categories);

// Limit to 8
$prod_categories = array_slice($prod_categories, 0, 8);

// Now do your foreach loop...
```